# Selecting and sorting data JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, filter

I need to develop simple app to select and sort data from JSON list, containing two rules - "include" and "sort_by"

Example:
**input data:**

```
{"data": [{"name": "John", "email": "john2@mail.com"},
          {"name": "John", "email": "john1@mail.com"},
          {"name": "Jane", "email": "jane@mail.com"}]}
```

**condition:**

```
{"condition": {"include": [{"name": "John"}], "sort_by": ["email"]}}
```

**output:**

```
{"result": [{"name": "John", "email": "john1@mail.com"},
            {"name": "John", "email": "john2@mail.com"}]}
```

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (you get a badge), and provide what you have tried or where you're having trouble. Include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt if possible.

Comment: @Yash Maheshwari don't know even how to start. You can give your solution from the scratch

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this result using [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to get the property by which you need to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and then [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)(using customized sort) it accordingly.

```js
const obj = {
  data: [
    { name: "John", email: "john2@mail.com" },
    { name: "John", email: "john1@mail.com" },
    { name: "Jane", email: "jane@mail.com" },
  ],
};

const test = {
  condition: {
    include: [{ name: "John" }],
    sort_by: ["email"],
  },
};

let prop;
for (let key in test.condition.include[0]) {
  prop = key;
}

const include_prop = test.condition.include[0][prop];
const sort_by_prop = test.condition.sort_by[0];

const result = obj.data
  .filter((o) => o[prop] === include_prop)
  .sort((a, b) => (b[sort_by_prop] > a[sort_by_prop] ? -1 : 1));

const resultObj = { result };
console.log(resultObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you want to do here, sort and filter...

```
const data = [
  {"name": "John", "email": "john2@mail.com"},
  {"name": "John", "email": "john1@mail.com"},
  {"name": "Jane", "email": "jane@mail.com"}
]
const sortAndInclude = (data, include, sortBy) => {
  //filter by name
  const newData = data.filter(x => x[include[0]] == include[1])
  
  // sort by sortBy
  newData.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aa = a[sortBy].toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
    var bb = b[sortBy].toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  if (aa < bb) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (aa > bb) {
    return 1;
  }

  // names must be equal
  return 0;
});
  
  return newData
  
}

console.log(sortAndInclude(data, ["name", "John"], ['email']))
```

Edit: Filter explanation...

The filter method returns a new array, which we call `newData`. The filter method iterates over an array and removes any element where the condition is false. In this case, we are calling the element `x`. We want the function to be reusable, so we are using `x[include[0]]` and `include[1]`. Our `include` variable is the second argument to the wider function, so when we call `sortAndInclude(data, ["name", "John"], ['email'])` include is an array with two elements `["name", "John"]`. So in the condition of the filter method when we say `x[include[0]] == include[1]` we are really saying `x["name"] == x["John"]`. So the filter method will remove any element where the element's name key does not have the value of 'John'.

[Here's some more info on filters.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is really helpfull! But i dont actually get this condition: 
"const newData = data.filter(x => x[include[0]] == include[1])".
(x["name"] ==["John"])?
 Could you please explain it more detail?

Comment: No problem, I've added an explanation of the function in my answer.